# subquery returning row in HQL

Tags: oracle, hibernate, orm, hql

I want to do following:

```
INSERT INTO Table0(value1, value2) 
SELECT 
    (SELECT t1.something1 FROM Table1 t1 WHERE t1.id = :t1id),
    (SELECT max(t2.something2) FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t2.some = :t2Some)
FROM Table1, Table2
```

But hibernate complains that I want to insert entity (Table1) as string (value1). It looks like subqueries in HQL returns entities instead of column values. Can I force it not to do so?

I know, that I can do like:

```
INSERT INTO Table0(value1, value2)
SELECT t1.something1, max(t2.something2) FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2 WHERE ...
```

but it generates bad SQL for Oracle, because there is `HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL` in SELECT and Oracle does not allow to do so.

Comment: Is it necessary to do this in Hibernate? Even if you find a way, next time you will need to refactor it, you face similar problems.

Comment: It is necessary as I want to use different DB engines for different deployments of my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like first query works now, maybe it was about Hibernate version.